# How do I apply Banach-Steinhaus to a sequence of real numbers $(x_k)$?

Tags: functional-analysis

How do I apply Banach-Steinhaus to a sequence of real numbers $(x_k)$?

My problem is the requirement that the collection be from $E \rightarrow F$, where $E$ is Banach and $F$ is normed.

Since real numbers are just $\mathbb{R}$, then what kind of transformations these are?

Comment: What are you trying to show?

Answer (score 0):

You can consider $x_k$ as a bounded linear operator $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ acting as $a \mapsto x_k a$.

The operator norm of $x_k$ is then precisely $|x_k|$. Hence you can apply Banach-Steinhaus to the collection $(x_k)_k$ to obtain

$$(x_k)_k \text{ is a bounded sequence in } \mathbb{R} \iff (x_ka)_k \text{ is a bounded sequence in } \mathbb{R}, \text{ for all } a \in \mathbb{R}$$

which is pretty clear.